# NSNotification NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate getting non-stop Notification messages

Tags: swift, ios11, icloud-drive

I am implementing saving to iCloud Drive in my application. Right now I am testing the app on the simulator. I can save a file on to the iCloud Drive and it appears on the drive as expected. In my code, I have implemented NotificationCenter.default.addObserver. The startQuery() gets called with the application is made active. Here is the code sample:

```
@objc func startQuery()
{
    stopQuery()
    query = documentQuery()
    print( "adding notifications" )
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(finishGatheringNotification(notifciations:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object:nil )
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didUpdateNotification(notifciations:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate, object:nil )
    query?.start()
}

@objc func stopQuery()
{
    guard let query = self.query else{
        return
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object:nil )
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate, object:nil )
    query.stop()
    self.query = nil

}

     @objc func finishGatheringNotification( notifciations:NSNotification ){
        print( "called finished gathering notification" )
        processICloudFiles(notifciations: notifciations )
    }

    @objc func didUpdateNotification( notifciations:NSNotification ){
        // This seems to be getting called non-stop
        print( "called updated notification" )
        processICloudFiles(notifciations: notifciations )
    }

    @objc func processICloudFiles( notifciations:NSNotification )
    {
        guard let query = query else{
            return
        }
        query.disableUpdates()
        var metaDataItems:[NSMetadataItem] = []

        if let queryResults = query.results as? [NSMetadataItem]{
            print( "query results:\(queryResults.count)")
            for result in queryResults{
                if let fileURL = result.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey ) as? NSURL{
                     print( "file found in iCloud:\(String(describing: fileURL.lastPathComponent))")
                    metaDataItems.append( result )
                }
            }
            if metaDataItems.count > 0{
                updateICloudFiles(metaDataItems: metaDataItems)
            }
        }
        query.enableUpdates()
    }
```

However, the selector for NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate is getting called no stop. I thought it was meant to get called only when the content of the iCloud disk changes. 
Any suggestions.
Thanks
Reza

Comment: Could it be updating the object in response to the notification? Can you create a minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I have updated my code with a little more detail. It is difficult to have a full example as it is tied to iCloud storage etc.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm using iCloud Drive and would like to get a notification to detect conflicts. So far I'm not getting any of my observers called at all. I'm observing NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate and NSNotification.Name.UIDocumentStateChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Try to deinitialize:

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: As I understand you need the notification active so that you will be informed when the content of the iCloud UbiquitousDocuments folder gets updated, so your app can respond appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Just got a message from Apple that this is a known bug and I have posted a bug report.